# Convex function: sufficient condition $\forall a>b,f(a)\geq f(b)+f'(b)(a-b)$ $\implies$ $f$ convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose $f\in C^1$, does the condition that $\forall a>b,f(a)\geq f(b)+f'(b)(a-b)$ imply $f$ is convex?

We know that $f$ is convex if and only if $\forall a,b, \ f(a)\geq f(b)+f'(b)(a-b)$. But I want to know whether the condition $\forall a>b,f(a)\geq f(b)+f'(b)(a-b)$ is sufficient or not.

Comment: @Learningonepageatatime  How about the other way around? As the my question indicates

Comment: Hint 1: try to prove the contrapositive- start with a non-convex $f$ and try to see if you can find an $a>b$ so that the condition doesn't hold.  Hint 2: try using the mean value theorem.